# JSON issue with execution

Tags: php, ajax, windows, json

I'm sure this is probably me being stupid but I want to confirm this issue. I am building a windows 8 app and loading in data from a mysql server and I can't seem to fix this issue. From a bit of reading I am guessing the issue is that the code is executing before the json request is this correct and is there a way to resolve it. The return is there because it is inside a function which returns the data and then displays it. The "SampleItems[0]" displays perfectly but the stuff inside the json wont but a console log shows it is getting data from the server. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    var sampleItems = [];
    sampleItems[0] = { group: sampleGroups[count], title: "New Image", subtitle: "", description: "", content: "", backgroundImage: "/images/add.png" };

        //this code calls to our cloud based service which gets the data which is needed and returns it in a JSON object back for this to handle
        $.getJSON('http://pumpstationstudios.com/tumapics/services/getimages.php', function (data) {
            var service_url = 'http://pumpstationstudios.com/tumapics/';
            var count = 1;


            images = data.items;
            $.each(images, function (index, image) {
                image.image = service_url + image.image;
                sampleItems[count] = { group: sampleGroups[count], title: "Hello", subtitle: "", description: "", content: "", backgroundImage: image.image };
                count++;
            });
        });

    return sampleItems;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638365/1741542) a similar question [javascript code execution and ajax async](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14638158/1741542) some hours ago

Essentially, what happens is

```
$.getJSON('http://.../getimages.php', function(data) {
// process data
});

// this runs *before* "process data"
return sampleItems;
```

This means, you return `sampleItems`, before it is filled by the `getJSON` callback function.

To solve this problem, you must do your processing in the callback function.